# Price Calculator Using Forms

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So here's the thing, I want to make a price calculator by letting the user fill up the form but it won't work. Also, I wanted to show the result on the input field. Thank you in advance.

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>

</title>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <form role="form" id="price" name="price">    
        <select class="" id="itemselect" onchange="calculate()">
            <option id="itemprice" value="1.500">Adult's T-Shirt</option>
            <option id="itemprice" value="1.250">Kid's T-Shirt</option>
            <option id="itemprice" value="3.000">Dubai Polo</option>
            <option id="itemprice" value="6.000">Aerocool Polo</option>
            <option id="itemprice" value="4.000">Aerocool Crewneck</option>
            <option id="itemprice" value="5.000">Hoodies</option>
        </select>
        <p><input type="text" id="qty" onchange="calculate()" value=""></p>
        <p><input type="text" id="result" value="" disabled></p>        
    </form>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function calculate(price){
            var item = document.getElementByID("itemselect").value;
            var qty = document.getElementByID("qty");
            
            item = parseInt(item);
            qty = parseInt(qty);
            
            var result = item*qty;
            
            document.getElementByID("result").value=result;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `getElementByID`, it's `getElementById`

Comment: and `var qty = document.getElementByID("qty").value;` instead of `var qty = document.getElementByID("qty");`

Comment: still the same.. result is not coming

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: works for me https://jsfiddle.net/5veg41xx/

Comment: This should be closed by a typographical error (offtopic). Don't round and round and round.

Comment: i don't know what went wrong, but I really appreciate all your reply guys. thank you so much!

Comment: This is the error: document.getElementByI`D`("qty"); must be lowercase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mistakes

1. Please change getElementByID by getElementById.
2. parseInt only parse value in integer so you multiplication give you only integer value so you have to parse in float. it's give you perfect output.

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>

</title>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <form role="form" id="price" name="price">    
        <select class="" id="itemselect" onchange="calculate()">
            <option id="itemprice" value="1.500">Adult's T-Shirt</option>
            <option id="itemprice" value="1.250">Kid's T-Shirt</option>
            <option id="itemprice" value="3.000">Dubai Polo</option>
            <option id="itemprice" value="6.000">Aerocool Polo</option>
            <option id="itemprice" value="4.000">Aerocool Crewneck</option>
            <option id="itemprice" value="5.000">Hoodies</option>
        </select>
        <p><input type="text" id="qty" onchange="calculate()" value=""></p>
        <p><input type="text" id="result" value="" disabled></p>        
    </form>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function calculate(price){
            var item = document.getElementById("itemselect").value || 0;

            var qty = document.getElementById("qty").value || 0;
            
            item = parseFloat(item).toFixed(2);
            qty = parseFloat(qty).toFixed(2);
            
            var result = parseFloat(item*qty).toFixed(2);
                            
            document.getElementById("result").value=result;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take care with `parseFloat`, it can give unexpected results. Try `Number(item)` instead!!

Comment: Try in your fiddle to select `Dubai Polo` and put `1.1` in the textbox. It should give `3.3` of result, but it gives `3.30000000000003`, that's because the floated comma.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Thank for you suggestion. I updated my answer with another safe way.

Comment: thank you guys for all your help, I am a beginner with javascript and your answers really means so much to me. At least now, I got better understanding with these codes.